# Is it normal to have the same visa and application number as someone else on a Bahrain visa?

Tags: visas, paperwork, applications, bahrain

Is it usual to have the same visa and application number as someone else? My Bahrain visit visa has the same information as my friend, and I am now suspicious of my visa agent.

Comment: Who is the other person? Did you submit your visa applications together (for example, for a family trip)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Chris H. The other person is a friend. We actually did the application through an agent, we didn't visit the embassy for it. We are currently suspecting the agent

Comment: Highly suspect. Typically applications and visas have distinct numbers that are specific to an individual, even if travelling together/dependents etc. Why did you use an agent in the first place?

Comment: See https://www.bahrain.bh/wps/portal/!ut/p/a1/nZHRToMwFIZfxV3skvRAWSmXSHBKZDOb6OjNUjq61Wwtw4bo2wsuJsYEN-3dSb6_-c75EUMrxDRv1ZZbZTTf9zMj69s5ENejXkpxjiGak3gRJuBOYdIBxXcAME56IHgInkKPULgsD14Wu3d-l88ygIheL-4fb2KAKT6Xf0YMMaFtbXeoqLamrU1j-X5d6TFIY2zVjKFVr8pelXzXcKV_jH28FmqDikkJkpZ445AyAMeXXDghhNwRxBdcur4EIb90B150dt1lpU_KZ472Cfx2lRMw7FF0osGgSffD8o-bpxc0qV6ORxZ1fRhtqzeLVv8ppD7k-YHidydN5GzmsCIajT4AxTAXiA!!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/